# import data from excel file to sql database Asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Any person can help me how to import data from excel file to SQL database Asp.net MVC.
I want to upload the result and comments of students in the assignment table in the result column.
The table is given[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6kG9.png) below.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example

Add DataSource

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Excel03ConString" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=YES'"/>
    <add name="Excel07ConString" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=YES'"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Add Namespaces

```
using System.IO;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Configuration;
```

**In Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase postedFile)

{
    string filePath = string.Empty;
    if (postedFile != null)
    {
        string path = Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/");
        if (!Directory.Exists(path))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
        }

        filePath = path + Path.GetFileName(postedFile.FileName);
        string extension = Path.GetExtension(postedFile.FileName);
        postedFile.SaveAs(filePath);

        string conString = string.Empty;
        switch (extension)
        {
            case".xls": //Excel 97-03.
                conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel03ConString"].ConnectionString;
                break;
            case".xlsx": //Excel 07 and above.
                conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel07ConString"].ConnectionString;
                break;
        }

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        conString = string.Format(conString, filePath);

        using (OleDbConnection connExcel = new OleDbConnection(conString))
        {
            using (OleDbCommand cmdExcel = new OleDbCommand())
            {
                using (OleDbDataAdapter odaExcel = new OleDbDataAdapter())
                {
                    cmdExcel.Connection = connExcel;

                    //Get the name of First Sheet.
                    connExcel.Open();
                    DataTable dtExcelSchema;
                    dtExcelSchema = connExcel.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
                    string sheetName = dtExcelSchema.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
                    connExcel.Close();

                    //Read Data from First Sheet.
                    connExcel.Open();
                    cmdExcel.CommandText = "SELECT * From [" + sheetName + "]";
                    odaExcel.SelectCommand = cmdExcel;
                    odaExcel.Fill(dt);
                    connExcel.Close();                           
                }
            }
        }

        conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Constring"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
        {
            using (SqlBulkCopy sqlBulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(con))
            {
                //Set the database table name.
                sqlBulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.Customers";

                //[OPTIONAL]: Map the Excel columns with that of the database table
                sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Id", "CustomerId");
                sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Name", "Name");
                sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Country", "Country");

                con.Open();
                sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(dt);
                con.Close();
            }
        }
    }

    return View();
}
```

**In View**

```
<body>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
        <input type="file" name="postedFile"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Import"/>
    }
</body>
```